# Writing an argument replacing macro

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

Suppose we have a list with an `_` in an arbitrary location. For example: `(a b c _ e f)`. I'm trying to write a macro which, for such a list, finds the `_` and replaces it with another value (say, `z`): `(a b c z e f)`.

What is the best approach for this?

Answer (score 6):

Are you sure you need a macro?  Using [replace](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/replace) should work fine as long as you quote the list:

```
(replace '{_ z} '(a b c _ e f)) ; =>  (a b c z e f)
```

Comment: This is elegant, but I mispoke in my question: what I need is not for the list to be returned, but to substituted for and then evaluated. How could one achieve this in ClojureScript where there is no `eval`?

Answer (score 1):

the @Josh answer is right, first you should decide if you really need macro for something. I can imagine a synthetic example. Let's pretend you want to define a function but need to track this `_` value for some reason (for logging maybe), to use it like this:

```
(defn-with-placeholder my-fn [a b c _ e] z
  (println a b c z e))
```

that's how you do this:

```
(defmacro defn-with-placeholder [name args placeholder & body]
  `(defn ~name ~(vec (replace {'_ placeholder} args))
     ~@body))
```

notice that i've used the same `replace` approach, which was proposed earlier.

let's test it in repl:

```
user> (defn-with-placeholder my-fn [a b _ d] placeholder 
        (println a b placeholder d))
#'user/my-fn
user> (my-fn 1 2 3 4)
1 2 3 4
nil
```

ok now it's pretty useless. Lets go further with exercise, and make a definition, that will gather all the omitted parameters to some collection (like functions rest parameters `& args`, but on different positions)
So we could define a macro `defn-with-omitted` that works like this:

```
(defn-with-omitted my-fn-2 [a _ c _ e f _ h] other-args
  (println :parameters a c e f h)
  (println :other-parameters other-args))
```

in repl:

```
user> (my-fn-2 1 100 2 200 3 4 300 5)
:parameters 1 2 3 4 5
:other-parameters {1 100, 3 200, 6 300}
nil
```

it gathers all the omitted data and puts it to `other-args` map, with arg-position to arg mapping.

To do this first of all we need to create a function which processes the arglist and gathers all omitted arguments:

```
(defn process-args [args]
  (reduce-kv (fn [[args omitted] idx arg]
               (if (= '_ arg)
                 (let [sym-name (gensym "omitted")]
                   [(conj args sym-name)
                    (assoc omitted idx sym-name)])
                 [(conj args arg) omitted]))
             [[] {}]
             args))
```

here's what it does:

```
user> (process-args '[a _ b c _ _ f g])
[[a omitted29608 b c omitted29609 omitted29610 f g] 
 {1 omitted29608, 4 omitted29609, 5 omitted29610}]
```

notice that i've used `gensym` here, not to shadow possible outer definitions.

so now it's quite easy to make the macro:

```
(defmacro defn-with-omitted [name args omitted-name & body]
  (let [[args omitted] (process-args args)]
    `(defn ~name ~args
       (let [~omitted-name ~omitted]
         ~@body))))
```

let's check the expansion:

```
(defn-with-omitted my-fn-2 [a _ c _ e f _ h] other-args
  (println :parameters a c e f h)
  (println :other-parameters other-args))
```

expands to:

```
(defn my-fn-2 [a omitted29623 c omitted29624 e f omitted29625 h]
  (let [other-args {1 omitted29623, 3 omitted29624, 6 omitted29625}]
    (println :parameters a c e f h)
    (println :other-parameters other-args)))
```

which is exactly what we want.